# URL amigável com JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, htaccess

Olá, pessoal!

Meu sistema é desenvolvido em JQuery, então faço as alterações de páginas sem carregamento, apenas com $.get().
A grande questão é: mesmo sem carregamento, preciso que as URL seja alterada, deixando o sistema ainda mais amigável. Já consigo fazer a alteração perfeitamente, fazendo todas as transações internas baterem perfeitamente com as alterações da URL. Porém, ao atualizar a página na URL atual, ou quando quero entrar através de uma dessas URL, cai em uma página inexistente, pois tudo é feito apenas na index.html.

Para exemplificar:
Todo o processo é feito na index.html, que chama alguns .js que fazem todo esse controle. Porém, quando clico no botão "perfil" e apresento essa página sem carregamento, altero a url para meusite.com/perfil. O problema acontece quando tento atualizar essa página. Ao atualizar, o erro 404 vai aparecer, pois não existe o arquivo index.html na pasta "perfil".
O que eu gostaria é que houvesse um tratamento e que ao entrar em meusite.com/perfil, fosse redirecionado para o index.html?pagina=perfil, por exemplo.

O que posso fazer?

Desde já, agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando o arquivo `.htaccess` para direcionar a uma página específica de erro 404 e nela fazer o redirecionamento para o `index.html` com o parâmetro em questão.

**1)** Crie uma página `.html` na pasta raiz para onde serão direcionados os erros **404**:

```
redir.html
```

**2)** Insira na página `redir.html` o código JavaScript que irá capturar o parâmetro e fazer o redirecionamento:

```
<script>
var url_ = location.href;
params = url_.split("/").pop();
location.href = "index.html?pagina="+params;
</script>
```

**3)** Insira no aquivo `.htaccess` o código:

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /redir.html
```

> Desta forma, caso seja acessada a URL `meusite.com/perfil`, será
>   redirecionado para `index.html?pagina=perfil`.